# npm install package global and link in one cmd

Tags: npm, package, global

I need to do npm install and link both in single cmd

So I am using

```
npm install -g NamPkg && npm link NamPkg
```

Is there any shorthand for this where I can mention NamPkg only once like :

```
npm install -g && npm link NamPkg

OR

npm install -g && link NamPkg
```

Bcoz I need to use this in Package.json 
and when the list grows more mentioning the same package names twice may become lengthy

```
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install -g NamPkg && npm link NamPkg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any shorthand where I can mention NamPkg only once

AFAIK there is no way of doing this either via npm scripts or bash.

I don't know if it fits your use case, but using a variable would save a little typing (in that you would only have to declare the package name once and could copy/paste the rest of the command).

```
"scripts": {
  "preinstall": "pkg='whatever'; npm i $pkg && npm link $pkg"
},
```